# Initial value problem of $y' = \sqrt{|y|}(y+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

i'm trying to determinate the solution of the intial value problem

$$y' = \sqrt{|y|}(y+1)$$

my solution was as follow

applying substitution as follow

let $u^{2} = y$ and $dy = 2u\ du$

$$2 \int du = \int u^{2} + 1\ dx $$

but i feel it's wrong

Answer (score 1):

$$y' = \sqrt{|y|}(y+1)$$

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{|y|}(y+1)
\\
\equiv \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y} (y + 1)} dy = \int 1\ dx
\\
\equiv \int \frac{2u}{u(u^2+1)} du = x + c
\\
\equiv 2 \int \frac{1}{u^2+1} du = x + c
\\
\equiv \tan^{-1}{\sqrt{y}} = \frac{1}{2}(x + c)
\\
\equiv \tan{(\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{y}})} = \tan{(\frac{x}{2}+c)}
\\
\equiv \sqrt{y} = \tan{(\frac{x}{2}+c)}
\\
\equiv y = \tan^2{(\frac{x}{2}+c)}
$$

Comment: and you can take it farther and solve for y as a function of x if you so desire

Answer (score 0):

You haven't yet established a relationship between $u$ and $x$ so you can't integrate the right hand side.

Things get a lot easier if you write things in Leibniz (differential) notation from the start.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{|y|}(y+1)$$
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{|y|}(y+1)}=dx$$
$$\int\frac{|y|^{-0.5}dy}{y+1}=\int dx$$
Now you can let $u^2=y$ and $dy=2u du$
$$\int\frac{|u^2|^{-0.5} 2u du}{u^2+1}=\int dx$$
$$\int\frac{2 du}{u^2+1}=x$$

and that ought to be in your table of integrals